# Convert a range of integer numbers to string and store the shortest common match in DB

Tags: java

I have a range of integers representing phone number ranges like:

```
2010000  -  2049999    carrier_id: 11
2450000  -  2519999    carrier_id: 17
```

I have to store this ranges somehow with the corresponding id in database table for a later search. The simple way could be to store each number in range but this will make the table very big (50000 entries just for the first range). The idea which i am trying to implement is to trim equal number of trailing zeros and nines at the end to make the list of entries to store shorter. Example for first range:

```
2010000  -  2049999  can be changed to 
201  -  204          by removing the trailing zeros and nines
[201, 202, 203, 204] // the list to be inserted in db
```

Instead of inserting each number from the range and look for an exact match i can now insert only 4 rows and look for number starts with 201, 202, 203, 204.

The code i am using:

```
    String start = 2010000; 
    String end   = 2049999;
    while (start.charAt(start.length()- 1)=='0' && end.charAt(end.length()-1)== '9'){
        start = start.substring(0, start.length()-1);
        end = end.substring(0, end.length()-1);
    }
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int st = Integer.parseInt(start);
    int en = Integer.parseInt(end);        
    for(int i = st; i <= en;i++){
            list.add(i);
    }
```

While this will work for most of ranges some ranges are yet not short enough.

Example :

```
2980400  -  2989799
29804  -  29897
[29804, 29805, 29806, 29807, 29808, 29809, 29810, 29811, 29812....29897] //93 elements
```

Desired output:

```
[29804, 29805, 29806, 29807, 29808, 29809, 2981, 2982, 2983, 2984, 2985,
 2986, 2987, 2988, 29890, 29891, 29892, 29893, 29894, 29895, 29896, 29897] // 22 elements
```

Another example:

```
3250100  -  3259999   
[32501, 32502, 32503, 32504, 32505, 32506, 32507, 32508, 32509, 32510, 32511 ... 32599] // instead of 
[32501, 32502, 32503, 32504, 32505, 32506, 32507, 32508, 32509, 3251, 3252, 
3253, 3254, 3255, 3256, 3257, 3258, 3259]
```

How can I shorten the list to insert as short as possible?

EDIT:

I am also open for other ways. The time complexity or readability of the java code is not important as long as the list to store is short and represents the hole range.

Comment: Why not simply use a table where you store the id and start and end of the range. In searches you can check whether your value is contained in the range.

Comment: I can not change the table structure because it is also used by other applications. It has only one column for number one for id. And the requirement is to keep this table as small as possible cause search result time has to be very short.

Comment: Are all numbers always the same length?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes.

Comment: Will you be searching the table using sql or load it into java and search there?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i wil be using sql in db2 database

Comment: What is the type of number column in db?

Comment: Since you are going to do the search in the db I see very little point in trying to optimise this more than you have already done, if you overcomplicate it you only increase the possibilities of bugs and/or bad data besides databases are good at handle many rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
 for(int i = st; i <= en;i++){
        if( (i ends with) 0 && (i+9 < en)){
            list.add(i with 0 stripped);
            i = i+9;
         }else
            list.add(i);
}
```

it could also possibly done with a recursive call when you find an i that ends with 0 with a new range that starts with i and ends with i+9

Comment: Thank you very much. That was just the right hint i was looking for. Shame on me that i didn't figure it out by myself.